# Access variable that was changed from another module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm studying Python and creating a simple chat bot. Consider I have a module with main function:

```
# bot.py
class QueueWrapper:
    pass

wrapper = QueueWrapper() # also tried with dict

def main():
    wrapper.queue = init_queue()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And consider there is an another module where i want to access `queue` from bot module, but function from this module gets invoked some time after `bot.py` module got invoked:

```
# another_module.py
from bot import wrapper

def create_job():
    wrapper.queue.do_smth() # <- error. object has no attribute ...
```

And when I try to access `queue` that should be in `wrapper` object I get and error saying there is no `queue` in `wrapper`. But if I run in debug mode over `bot` module I can clearly see that `wrapper.queue` contains object. But when `create_job` function from `another_module.py` is invoked it doesn't know that there were a `queue` in `wrapper`.

The problem here in my opinion is that var `queue` from `bot.py` gets initialized after `main()` and `init_queue()` had finished working but module itself gets imported into `another_module` before that.

What am I doing wrong (probably missing something about variable scope) and how can I get my `wrapper.queue` initialized in when `create_job()` is invoked?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The __main__-part isn't run on imports. If you always want to set `wrapper.queue = init_queue()` you should place that below the definition of `wrapper = ...`

Comment: ... or put it in the `__init__` method of QueueWrapper.

Comment: @ekhumoro Sorry for not responding. I've tried your answer and it worked. Mostly because I moved `init_queue()` out from `main` and import started working as i expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), so that the `queue` attribute is automatically initialised when it is first accessed:

```
class QueueWrapper:
    _queue = None

    @property
    def queue(self):
        if self._queue is None:
            self._queue = init_queue()
        return self._queue

wrapper = QueueWrapper()
```